# Change <Script> Structure

Tags: html, mailchimp

I need to insert a piece of code in my website. The code is to connect my website to MailChimp:

```
<script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/0dc30c560570fa73fdd90b4ec/2cfddd4d9fb2316dbdb3b3c48.js");</script>
```

The problem is that my website platform just let me add code that starts with `<script>` and ends with `</script>`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyl7A.png

Is there a way to change the code structure to start with `<script>` , and then add the `id="mcjs"`?

Comment: What exactly you have to do that you need to add an id to your script tag?

Comment: @vitomadio I hope the OP tried without the id before asking here. It's possible the MailChimp script looks for this id in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `<script>` that uses [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) and adds the MailChimp `script`.

```
<script>
document.write('<script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/0dc30c560570fa73fdd90b4ec/2cfddd4d9fb2316dbdb3b3c48.js");<\/script>')
</script>
```